# LaTeX editor with project management for Mac

Tags: macos, text-editors, latex

I tried a few of the LaTeX editors for OS X. TexMaker, TexWorks, TexShop and TextMate/BBEdit offer syntax highlighting and some additional features to edit single tex files.

On Linux I've been using Kile for LaTeX editing. The outstanding feature is the 'project' mode, which opens a project view with a side pane. You can open several tex documents and save them in a hierarchical folder structure and thus split your chapters up in several files with a main file where you include each chapter. You can also add images etc. It's much like an Eclipse project. That's very useful for large projects like a thesis or research paper.

Question: Is there a LaTeX editor for OS X that offers similar options?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [the website](http://kile.sourceforge.net/):

> What is Kile?
>
> Kile is a user friendly TeX/LaTeX editor for the KDE desktop environment. KDE is available for many architectures such as PC, Mac, and BSD.

and it's downloadeable at [DarwinPorts](http://kile.darwinports.com/) and [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/kile)

Comment: True. What I meant was a 'native' Mac editor. One of the many uberfancy apps only avalaible for Mac. It's not really fun to use DarwinPorts, is it :) ?

Comment: @emempe: The Qt toolkit, which KDE is based on and so, I assume, Kile as well, has a pretty native-like feel.  Compiling Qt for the Mac is brutal, though, least it was for me: took 27 hours.

Answer (score 3):

TextMate supports projects. There is a "project drawer" in which you can have several files organised in a hierarchical structure. You can save your project, open it later, etc.

Then you can use, e.g., [rubber](http://rubber.sf.net/) to compile your project. Of course rubber doesn't know anything about TextMate projects, but it doesn't need to: it'll find the dependencies automatically and compile everything that is out-of-date; just point it to your main Latex file. It's fairly easy to configure TextMate so that you can launch rubber by hitting a keyboard shortcut in TextMate.